# Powershell: Simple Foreach Adding

Tags: powershell, addition

So I'm trying to simple add the value of 5 `.Responsetime's` together using a `foreach` loop but I can't get it to work:

```
function go
{
$ping_cycle = test-connection -count 5 -computername www.google.com | select Responsetime
$sum = 0
foreach($item in $ping_cycle)
{
[void]$sum +$item.responsetime
}
$sum
}
```

go

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to increment your $sum instead of reassigning it :

```
$sum += $item.responsetime
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(test-connection www.google.com -count 5 | `
      Measure-Object -Property ResponseTime -sum).sum
```